# CSS 3 - Unsure?

Tags: css

There is a huge use of rounded corners in web design, and as far as i'm aware this issue has been addressed in CSS3 so as to avoid having to hack around with images for curved corners etc.

However, by using built in rounded corner capabilities of CSS3 - will this affect the display of the site cross browser?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Whether using things that not all browsers support is a good idea? Or are you asking whether all browsers support CSS3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with any other feature you need to weigh the following factors:

- The chances that the specification will change (given that it has not reached Recommendation status)
- The level of support for the feature in the browsers your visitors are using
- The severity of the consequences of that feature not being available for some users

A feature that makes pages look a little bit prettier is a smaller loss than a feature which lets users submit payment information (for example).

Answer (score 2):

The browsers that don't support CSS3 will show sharp corners.

In general, it may not be a good idea to use those CSS options that are not supported by the vast majority of the browsers currently in use.

Alternatively you can use vendor-specific extensions along with the CSS3 styles. This will cover a good portion of browsers out there.

```
border-radius: 2em;
-moz-border-radius: 2em;
-webkit-border-radius: 2em;
```

Comment: So in general as a web designer its probably not a good idea to use this feature?

Comment: You will be sued if a user injures themselves on those sharp corners.

Comment: I will write a notice: "This page if for 18+ only".

Comment: @Goober: I believe it is not a good idea to use whatever is not supported by the majority of browsers yet. Inclusive this display:table option because IE8 spread is not that great yet.

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 is not a standard.  It is not universally adopted.  I strongly recommend not using it, at least not yet.

Even more important... do you absolutely need rounded corners?  Will consumers not buy your products because the corners are not round?  Rounded corners cost significantly more than any value they could possibly be worth.

Comment: Heck, I don't *absolutely need* images either! And who's that jaba-kid everyone's talking about? OK - seriously - when you have paying clients with a ready design, you can't tell them you'll do something *similar* to what they want.

Comment: I wouldn’t buy a product from a website without rounded corners!

Comment: @Gumbo you are the exception to the rule then.  After working for a website that gets millions of visitors a day and seeing the results of comparative usability tests rounded corners tend to harm the user experience.  When websites focus on presentation and usability first they tend to fail in usability tests pretty significantly.  Consumers are interested in efficiency, good content, and a valuable product.  Consumers are significantly less interested in how pretty the website is.  If prettiness harms efficiency you have probably lost a customer.

Comment: CSS3 is not a standard. It is not universally adopted. I strongly recommend you use it, play with it, get used to it, enjoy it, taste the future, and help develop the means to support older browsers whilst getting all the benefits CSS3 affords us. It's more or less here already.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the browsers that support it. I'd advice not using it until the major browsers can handle it correctly. An overview of which browser can handle which CSS3 properties can be found on http://www.quirksmode.com/

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to have easy, almost-cross-browser rounded corners, is to use a jQuery plugin called (yes you guessed it) rounded corners. You can find it at

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/corners

Last time I checked it said it supported IE6, but it didn't.